# Custom jquery AJAX method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to find a good way to achieve this.  If you have any other better suggestions, I'm all ears.

Basically, my site has a bunch of ajax calls.  However, I feel like these should be called in a such a way so I don't have to repeat code. Especially the beforeSend method.  I don't want to have to type the check methods below everytime.  How do I approach this so I dont have to type the check methods everytime? They can have different methods added on to the ones mentioned below, but the 2 below will ALWAYS have to be called.  I'm even okay instantiating the ajax call in a different way.

Currently, I have this all over the place in different flavors:

```
var Params = {};
    Params.type = "POST";
    Params.url = '/this/is/my/url';
    Params.cache = false;
    Params.timeout = 180000;
    Params.processData = true;
    Params.data = {
        action: "ajax",
        method: "coolMethod",
    };

    Params.dataType = "json";
    Params.beforeSend = function () {
         checkIfUserHasLoggedOut();
         checkSomeOtherThings();
    };
    Params.error = function (xhr, status, error) {

    };
    Params.success = function (data) {

    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to setup the default parameters for the ajax request

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    timeout: 180000,
    processData: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
         checkIfUserHasLoggedOut();
         checkSomeOtherThings();
    }
})
```

then use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with the specific parameters, which will change in all calls anyway

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data: {...},
    success: ....,
    failure: ....
})
```

Comment: What if i want to add onto beforeSend but not overwrite it?

Comment: Well how do I add on to it?  suppose i want to run console.log within the particular ajax call.  how do i achieve this?